# unique true constraints is not works well

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I single fact true for a few attributes in the entity and after i fact schema update --force and when it i fact add data exists in the database, I find this error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_101C7E5A6C6E55B5'

code entity:

```
<?php

    namespace test\MedBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


    /**
     * Apps
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="apps",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"nom", "prenom","age","class"})}
    )
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="test\MedBundle\Repository\AppsRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nom","prenom","class","age"}, message="Cette champ existe déja.")

     */
    class Apps
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $nom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="class", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $class;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $prenom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $age;


          /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        public $path;

         /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;


       /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Med",inversedBy="apps")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_med", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
         */
      private $med;

       /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage",mappedBy="apps")
        */
        private $comment;

       /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
        */

        private $updatedAt;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="nbr_modif", type="string", nullable=true)
        */

        private $unbr_modif;


        /**
         * @ORM\PreUpdate
        */
        public function nbremodif() {
            $this->setUnbrModif($this->unbr_modif+1);
        }

    }
```

My controller

```
public function addAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $x= $request->request->get('k');

          for( $i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){

        $nom = $request->request->get('nom'.$i);
        $prenom = $request->request->get('prenom'.$i);
        $age = $request->request->get('age'.$i);
        $class = $request->request->get('sexe'.$i);

          $cop = new Apps();  
          $cop->setAge($age);
          $cop->setNom($nom);
          $cop->setPrenom($prenom);
          $cop->setClass($class);
          $cop->setPath("path test");
          $em->persist($cop);
          $em->flush();
           }
            } //end for

         return $this->render('MedBundle:Apps:form.html.twig');


        }
```

What is the solution for when he added the data we see a message of Alert told him that this data is already exists in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a unique constraint on multiple fields you are using `UniqueEntity` as you should:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"nom","prenom","class","age"}, message="...")
```

**But** You should remove `unique=true` because this constraint apply on an unique field (and not the multiple constraint)

You can find an example [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"host", "port"},
 *     errorPath="port",
 *     message="This port is already in use on that host."
 * )
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Host")
     */
    public $host;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $port;
}
```

Then , to trigger validation used by `Assert` (like `UniqueEntity`) you can use the [validator service[doc]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service).

This service is called automatically if you do a form

```
/*... $cop->setPath("path test"); ...*/
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($cop);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    /*
     * Uses a __toString method on the $errors variable which is a
     * ConstraintViolationList object. This gives us a nice string
     * for debugging.
     */
    $errorsString = (string) $errors;

    return new Response($errorsString);
} else {
    $em->persist($cop);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Same problem my friend
that is what I find now

 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '1-1-1-1' pour la clef 'UNIQ_101C7E5A6C6E55B5A625945BA13010B2ED4B199F'

Comment: it is not exactly the same problem ;) How do you bind and valid your form in the controller?

Comment: You should edit your question when you want to add some code. I did for you for this time ;) I've edited my answer

Comment: I uses this code and works well,
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($cop);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $errorsString = (string) $errors;

    return new Response($errorsString);

 it displays errors but the problem now that the display of the errerue is not well
here are example of Validation Error Message
Object(test\MedBundle\Entity\Apps).nom:
Cette champ existe déja. (code 23bd9dbf-6b9b-41cd-a99e-4844bcf3077f)


What is the solution for well displayed error message

Comment: You should ask a new question when you have a new question.